# Not able to capture API response in chrome extension V3

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v3

I've developed a chrome extension. I am not able to capture the API response but I can see the response in the network console.

Below is my code

```
async function generateUniqueId(){
   let uniqueId = Date.now();
   let formData = new FormData();
   formData.append("userId",uniqueId);
   fetch('http://localhost:3000/v1/registerUser',{
    method:'POST',
    body:formData
     }).then((response)=>{
          console.log(response);
          chrome.storage.local.set({'userId': uniqueId}, function() {
            console.log('Value is set to ' + Date.now());
          });                      
      }).catch((error)=>{console.log(error)});
}
```

In the below image you can see the response in the Network tab but when I print it in the console it's showing empty. Can someone please help?

[image]

Comment: you are not using fetch correctly ... it's `fetch(url).then(response => response.text()).then(data => here is the data)` - though, your code isn't using response at all anyway, so not sure what you expect that code to achieve - did you need to use the response from the fetch at all?

Comment: I need one of the params that I am getting in the response

Comment: what is a "param"? is it a header? is it in the response body? currently all you do is log the response, you don't even try to access the response body, so it's impossible to know what you mean and therefore not possible to help much more than I already have